# Non-Forms Graphics Manipulations

Tags: c#, image, graphics, service

I need to be able to create images, but not in a Windows Form application.  I'm working on a way to convert ZPL Zebra Printer language to images.  It will be strictly a class used in a Windows Service.  Everything I see shows how to display images or manipulate graphics within a windows form, but there will be absolutely no visual component of the image creation I need to do.

Does anyone have any recomendations, suggestions, or tutorials on either using GDI+ in a Windows Service, or perhaps an affordable .NET library for graphics manipulations?

Comment: GDI is a dinosaur, you'd better use WPF for this. All the WPF graphics manipulation classes are independent of device, so you should have no problem with that.

Comment: The graphics isn't the big deal, nothing special is needed to draw into a bitmap and that will work just fine a service.  It is interpreting the ZPL printer language that is the hard part.  Contact Zebra first, this can't be a unique requirement.